# Is it possible to have an AlertViewController be presented after another?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uialertview

I want to have a `UIAlertViewController` that presents some text, and when you click "ok" it causes another `UIAlertController` to pop up and it will present the user with two options to choose from (go to main, restart game). this is the code I wrote and it brings up this error:

> "2015-11-16 22:29:21.438 MemoryCardGameTest_01[1917:46708] Warning:
>   Attempt to present   on
>    which is already
>   presenting (null)"

```
 func showWinMessage() {

    let userMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Victory! you win with... clicks \(ref2.clickCounter) and \(ref2.timeCounter) seconds", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

    }

    userMessage.addAction(action);

    self.presentViewController(userMessage, animated: true, completion: nil);


    println("victory achieved");


}

func showUserMessage(){
    let newMessage = UIAlertController(title: "whatwouldyouliketodonext?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    let goToUI = UIAlertAction(title: "goToUI", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        println("gotoUI was clicked");

    }

    let playAgain = UIAlertAction(title: "PlayAgain", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        println("playAgain was clicked");
    }

    newMessage.addAction(goToUI);
    newMessage.addAction(playAgain);

    self.presentViewController(newMessage, animated: true, completion: nil);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This roughly does what you want.  Just make sure you don't call it in `viewDidLoad` as you can get an error like you mentioned. Try `viewDidAppear` or something.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "First message", message: "This is the first message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
        // ...
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Second message", message: "This is the second message", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
            // ...
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
            // ...
        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Essentially I just set the second view to appear in OKAction of the first alertController.

Comment: works like a charm! thank you! (changed it a little bit, placed the code in a method that would be called at the end of the game and it works fine). Just didn't think about using the "cancel" option before calling another alert controller.

Comment: @TaliKatzman No problem. Like I said, it's a bit rough, but with some cleanup it should be more readable. If I were you I would think about presenting a modal view rather than multiple alerts. This way you can probably deal with everything you want with a more comfortable UX on one view without have lots of things pop up everywhere. Just my 50 cents though.